# copy Nuget packages with my project in UWP

Tags: nuget, win-universal-app, nuget-package

I have a `UWP` Project with some nuget packages installed, NuGet now downloads and stores a copy of the packages in a global packages folder located in my `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` folder. I want to move My project into another computer, How Can I move it with packages this project needs to? I don't want to search in that folder and find the desired packages and move them too, I want the packages stick in my project

Answer (score 0):

You basically don't need to do anything. As you have figured out, Nuget stores a local copy of those packages in your project, so if you open that up on a different computer, all you have to is to right-click the solution and choose "Restore NuGet Packages" to have those loaded. It will then create a global cache of packages for you.

Or are you asking how to disable the global package cache?

Comment: could you please tell me how to disable global package cache? when I choose restore missing packages nothing happens